# How to pass multiple commands to a single command in bash using &&?

Tags: bash

Currently I have a script that does some extra processing, but ultimately calls the command the user passed (FYI, this is to run some commands in a docker container, but we'll call it `foo.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# ...
runner "$@"
```

This works great (e.g. `foo.sh echo HI`), until the users wants to pass multiple commands to be run:

e.g.: `foo.sh echo HI && echo BYE`

`&&` is of course interpreted by the ambient shell before being passed into arguments.

Is there a workaround or means of escaping `&&` that might work?

Comment: `runner bash -c "echo HI && echo BYE"`

Comment: ...otherwise, you're writing a whole new command language. Which I've actually done before -- [`execline`](https://skarnet.org/software/execline/) is a good source of inspiration to consider, built for graceful use in just the kind of scenario your question anticipates. (To be clear, `execline` is not mine, but something I've used as food for thought in building a toolset for related purposes)

Comment: With respect to the general limitation, though, it's a feature, not a bug. If `"$@"` could expand to content parsed as syntax, passing untrusted data around in bash would be effectively impossible.

Answer (score 3):

An idiom that often comes in handy for this kind of case:

```
cmds_q='true'
add_command() {
  local new_cmd
  printf -v new_cmd '%q ' "$@"
  cmds_q+=" && $new_cmd"
}

add_command echo HI
add_command echo BYE
runner bash -c "$cmds_q"
```

The big advantage here is that `add_command` can be called with arbitrary arguments (after the first one defining the command to run, of course) with no risk of those arguments being parsed as syntax / used in injection attacks, so long as the caller never directly modifies `cmds_q`.